# Query to find when identifier changes

Tags: database, database-design, ms-access-2010

I am trying to identify when two employees who are married, but divorce and get their own single policies. Or if there are two employees with single policies and get married then going under one policy.

Currently I've built queries and tables to parse out data from the HIPAA 834 file format into separate fields the:
 *Employee Indicator (Y or N)
*Individual's policy ID
*Individual SSN

*Concatenated the employee indicator and SSN

One file is the latest one sent to vendors and the other file is the one previous file.

The tables I'm using look like:
Table 1 (file sent 6/1/15) - Employee indicator, Policy #, SSN, Concatenate
Table 2 (file sent 7/1/15) - Employee indicator, Policy #, SSN, Concatenate

An example of an employee and spouse divorcing and each getting their own policy is below:
Table 1 (File 6/1/15)
Y - 123456 - 999110000 - Y999110000
**N - 123456 - 000119999 - N000119999**

This would mean the first person is the employee under policy ID 123456. The second person is the Spouse, due to having the N indicator and the same policy number.

If Table 2 (file 7/1/15) is the values are:
Y - 123456 - 999110000 - Y999110000
**Y - 987654 - 000119999 - Y000119999**

So the output in my final query would show the before and after from Table 2 an Table 1:
Y - 987654 - 000119999 - Y000119999
N - 123456 - 000119999 - N000119999

There are new hires and terms on the eligibility files as well, and do not not want them in the output. I really only care about if the same SSN is on both files and if the Employee indicator changed to one of them.

Here's what I have so far, and it's not working, so take it with a grain of salt, it may need recreated altogether.

```
SELECT [Table 2].Employee, [Table 2].[Policy ID], [Table 2].SSN,
     [Table 2].Concatenate, [Table 1].SSN, [Table 1].Concatenate
FROM [Table 2] INNER JOIN [Table 1] ON [Table 2].SSN = [Table 1].SSN
WHERE (
    (([Table 2].SSN)=[Table 1]![SSN])
AND (([Table 2].Concatenate)<>[Table 1]![Concatenate])
AND (([Table 1].SSN)=[Table 2]![SSN])
AND (([Table 1].Concatenate)<>[Table 2]![Concatenate])
);
```